# How to convert latex to normal/raw mathematical equations?

Tags: latex, mathjax, tex

Can anyone suggest me any method or library which can convert a latex math to normal expression (x^2+2x+sin(x)).
So far I've found a code which can do it but it cannot convert \sqrt[3]{....} to cuberoot(....) or root(3,....)

The code:

```
 function MQtoAM(tex,display) {
        var nested,lb,rb,isfuncleft,curpos,c,i;
          tex = tex.replace(/\\:/g,' ');
        tex = tex.replace(/\\operatorname{(\w+)}/g,' $1');
          if (!display) {
          while ((i = tex.lastIndexOf('\\left|'))!=-1) { //found a left |)
            rb = tex.indexOf('\\right|',i+1);
                if (rb!=-1) {  //have a right |  - replace with abs( )
              isfuncleft = tex.substring(0,i).match(/(arcsinh|arccosh|arctanh|arcsech|arccsch|arccoth|arcsin|arccos|arctan|arcsec|arccsc|arccot|sinh|cosh|tanh|sech|csch|coth|ln|log|exp|sin|cos|tan|sec|csc|cot)(\^\d+)?$/);
                    tex = tex.substring(0,rb) + ")" + (isfuncleft?')':'') + tex.substring(rb+7);
                    tex = tex.substring(0,i) + (isfuncleft?'(':'') + "abs(" + tex.substring(i+6);
                } else {
                    tex = tex.substring(0,i) + "|" + tex.substring(i+6);
                }
            }
            tex = tex.replace(/\\text{\s*or\s*}/g,' or ');
            tex = tex.replace(/\\text{all\s+real\s+numbers}/g,'all real numbers');
          tex = tex.replace(/\\text{DNE}/g,'DNE');
            tex = tex.replace(/\\varnothing/g,'DNE');
            tex = tex.replace(/\\Re/g,'all real numbers');
          } else {
            tex = tex.replace(/\\Re/g,'RR');
          }
        tex = tex.replace(/\\begin{.?matrix}(.*?)\\end{.?matrix}/g, function(m, p) {
          return '[(' + p.replace(/\\\\/g,'),(').replace(/&/g,',') + ')]';
        });
          tex = tex.replace(/\\le(?=(\b|\d))/g,'<=');
          tex = tex.replace(/\\ge(?=(\b|\d))/g,'>=');
        tex = tex.replace(/\\ne(?=(\b|\d))/g,'!=');
        tex = tex.replace(/\\pm/g,'+-');
          tex = tex.replace(/\\approx/g,'~~');
          tex = tex.replace(/(\\arrow|\\rightarrow)/g,'rarr');
        tex = tex.replace(/\\cup/g,'U');
        tex = tex.replace(/\\times/g,'xx');
          tex = tex.replace(/\\left\\{/g,'lbrace').replace(/\\right\\}/g,'rbrace');
          tex = tex.replace(/\\left/g,'');
          tex = tex.replace(/\\right/g,'');
          tex = tex.replace(/\\langle/g,'<<');
          tex = tex.replace(/\\rangle/g,'>>');
          tex = tex.replace(/\\cdot/g,'*');
          tex = tex.replace(/\\infty/g,'oo');
          tex = tex.replace(/\\nthroot/g,'root');
        tex = tex.replace(/\\mid/g,'|');
          tex = tex.replace(/\\/g,'');
          tex = tex.replace(/sqrt\[(.*?)\]/g,'root($1)');
          tex = tex.replace(/(\d)frac/g,'$1 frac');
          while ((i=tex.indexOf('frac{'))!=-1) { //found a fraction start
            nested = 1;
            curpos = i+5;
            while (nested>0 && curpos<tex.length-1) {
                curpos++;
                c = tex.charAt(curpos);
                if (c=='{') { nested++;}
                else if (c=='}') {nested--;}
            }
            if (nested==0) {
                tex = tex.substring(0,i)+"("+tex.substring(i+5,curpos)+")/"+tex.substring(curpos+1);
            } else {
                tex = tex.substring(0,i) + tex.substring(i+4);
            }
          }
        //separate un-braced subscripts using latex rules
        tex = tex.replace(/_(\w)(\w)/g, '_$1 $2');
        tex = tex.replace(/(\^|_)([+\-])([^\^])/g, '$1$2 $3');  
          tex = tex.replace(/\^(\w)(\w)/g, '^$1 $2');
          tex = tex.replace(/_{([\d\.]+)}\^/g,'_$1^');
          tex = tex.replace(/_{([\d\.]+)}([^\^])/g,'_$1 $2');
          tex = tex.replace(/_{([\d\.]+)}$/g,'_$1');
        tex = tex.replace(/_{(\w+)}$/g,'_($1)');
          tex = tex.replace(/{/g,'(').replace(/}/g,')');
          tex = tex.replace(/lbrace/g,'{').replace(/rbrace/g,'}');
          tex = tex.replace(/\(([\d\.]+)\)\/\(([\d\.]+)\)/g,'$1/$2');  //change (2)/(3) to 2/3
          tex = tex.replace(/\/\(([\d\.]+)\)/g,'/$1');  //change /(3) to /3
          tex = tex.replace(/\(([\d\.]+)\)\//g,'$1/');  //change (3)/ to 3/
          tex = tex.replace(/\/\(([\a-zA-Z])\)/g,'/$1');  //change /(x) to /x
          tex = tex.replace(/\(([\a-zA-Z])\)\//g,'$1/');  //change (x)/ to x/
        tex = tex.replace(/\^\(-1\)/g,'^-1');
          tex = tex.replace(/\^\((-?[\d\.]+)\)/g,'^$1');
        tex = tex.replace(/\/\(([\a-zA-Z])\^([\d\.]+)\)/g,'/$1^$2');  //change /(x^n) to /x^n
          tex = tex.replace(/\(([\a-zA-Z])\^([\d\.]+)\)\//g,'$1^$2/');  //change (x^n)/ to x^n/
        tex = tex.replace(/\+\-/g,'+ -'); // ensure spacing so it doesn't interpret as +-
        tex = tex.replace(/text\(([^)]*)\)/g, '$1');
        return tex;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll give a solution for this specific case, but this is not always possible, since LaTeX doesn't guarantee that math expressions are valid<sup>1</sup>. LaTeX is also a [Turing Complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) programming language, so someone can always write an equation you can't convert.

In this particular case you need to replace the line:

```
tex = tex.replace(/sqrt\[(.*?)\]/g,'root($1)');
```

with

```
tex = tex.replace(/sqrt\[(.*?)\]\{(.*?)\}/g,'root($1, $2)');
```

The "$number" parts in the right side mean "copy the stuff in the number-th parentheses from the left side". Here I just told it to look for the stuff in square/curly brackets and act accordingly. This style of search and replace is called [regular expression parsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX). I recommend learning to write your own so you can add to the number of things your parser understands.

For example, you could add a line:

```
tex = tex.replace(/sqrt\{(.*?)\}/g,'squareroot($1)');
```

to deal with simple square roots.

Sadly, every language implements regular expressions differently(especially which things need a "\" in front of them), so you'll have to experiment a little to find what works in JavaScript.

<sup>1 <sub>This is one good reason why it is best practice to automatically convert formulas to LaTeX when writing articles, rather than writing them directly in LaTeX. It is extremely common to find published papers with invalid math because people write directly in LaTeX and then the mistake isn't visible because of how hard it is to spot mistakes in raw LaTeX source.</sub></sup>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for your contribution. This is an excellent first answer.